# Will Honeycomb get an update to add email search (Xoom)?

Tags: email, motorola-xoom

I am an avid user of Android and resisted the urge to get an iPad in favor of a Xoom - staying loyal to Android.  I was very disappointed to learn that the email function (which I sync with a corporate exchange server) does not have a search function.  Hard to believe.  As a business traveler, getting thousands of emails, it is critical to be able to search my email.  Does anyone know if this will be addressed.  I do not want o have to use a third party app like touchdown.  Please advise.  Thank you!

Comment: I don't think this is a Xoom problem so much as it is an Android problem. The non-Gmail Email app with Android has been lacking in features for so long I think it's a foregone conclusion that people are going to go out and choose something else.

Comment: I am not sure who should be addressing the issue (Motorola or Android) - but if you can't search email, you cut out a huge potential user base.  How would one go about asking Android?

Answer (score 1):

To address your question in the comments: Star [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4709) and perhaps leave a comment. Hopefully Google will take notice and improve the email app!

In the meantime, though, I do suggest using a third-party app.  Depend on your company's rules, you could even create a secondary Gmail account and either have your work emails forwarded to it or have Gmail grab mail from your work account via POP3 or IMAP, and then you could use the Gmail app for search.